# Test if an array contains an element from another array with Hamcrest

Tags: testing, rest-assured, hamcrest

I actually have two types of data:

```
a = ["1", "2", "3", "3", "5"]
b = ["7", "2"]

given()
       .header("Content-Type", "application/json").
when()
       .post(this.url).
then()
       .statusCode(200)
       .contentType("application/json")
       .body(myPathToData, everyItem(haveOneOrMoreElementFrom(a)));
```

I would like to test, with Hamcrest, in my body response after my rest-assured request, if b (element received) contains one or more element from a (`haveOneOrMoreElementFrom` in my example).

Is it also possible to make a function in my body response?

Solution:

I found a possible solution:
`everyItem(hasItem(isIn(a)))`

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the solution to check if `b` contains at least one element from `a` is

```
assertThat(b, hasItemInArray(isIn(a))); // for arrays

assertThat(b, hasItem(isIn(a))); // for collections
```

In case of Rest-assured, it would be

```
...

then()
       .body(pathToData, hasItem(isIn(a)));
```

---

In Hamcrest 2 `org.hamcrest.Matchers::isIn` methods are deprecated, so it is recommended to use `is(in(a))` or just `in(a)` instead.